# Lektor installation fails on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, installation, lektor

Installing Lektor using the curl command from getlektor.com appears to work and appropriate files are present in the `/usr/local/bin/` directory after the process completes.

However, `which lektor` shows nothing despite `/usr/local/bin` being in the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a python version problem. Invoking `python` on this machine starts a python 3.x environment and the lektor install script is expecting python 2.x.

The problem can be solved by downloading the install script to a file and changing the line that invokes the python script:

`$ curl -sf https://www.getlektor.com/install.sh > install.sh`

Edit line 19 of the `install.sh` file to invoke python 2.x (in this case I have python 2.x installed and linked as `python2`):

`...
 16     exit 1
 17   fi
 18
 19   python2 - <<'EOF'`   <- change here from python to python2

 `20 if 1:
 21
 22     import os
 ...`

then change the mode of the script to be executable and run:

`$ chmod +x install.sh`

`$ ./install.sh`